# Tab bar not showing when call new activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tabs

My code

```
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("main_jobs", 
                        new Intent(context,Job_Description.class)
                        .putExtra("line", str_line).putExtra("limit",str_limit)
                        .putExtra("limit",""+0)
                        .putExtra("Alert", false)
                        .putExtra("str_location", str_loc)
                        .putExtra("str_Descrption",str_descjob)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                        .getDecorView();
                                              setContentView(view);
```

I am using this code to open new activity with tab but tab bar not showing and 
not any error get
please help me how we can show tab bar to open new activity

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you are using tabhost ryt ?

Comment: yes  i am using Tabhost

Comment: how many tabs you having?

Comment: i have only four tab and i am calling Jobsearch class from login class , both classes not in tabs but i want to show tab bar.

Comment: post code here or put it in googledrive and give link. without code cant do anything.

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0fH8r2O9pgOMU1acmx3eXRORGs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: run this project and click on search button and after click on star and login (email- johnxxx@gmail.com pass- john24)

Comment: I want tab bar when open job search after login (class is                      com.jobDiagnosis.LoginActivity

Comment: put it as rar dude, its confusing.

Comment: click on file option on google drive and press download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Example :
Consider three tabs here
First in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    private static final String TAB1 = "TAB1";
    private static final String TAB2 = "TAB2";
    private static final String TAB3 = "TAB3";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB1);
        tab1.setIndicator(TAB1);
        Intent Intent1 = new Intent(this, Tab1.class);
        tab1.setContent(Intent1);


        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB2);
        tab2.setIndicator(TAB2);
        Intent Intent2 = new Intent(this, Tab2.class);
        tab2.setContent(Intent2);


        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB3);
        tab3.setIndicator(TAB3);
        Intent Intent3 = new Intent(this, Tab3.class);
        tab1.setContent(Intent3);


        tabHost.addTab(tab1); 
        tabHost.addTab(tab2); 
        tabHost.addTab(tab3); 
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Then three classes Tab1.java , Tab2.java and Tab3.java
And three xml files to that classes.

try it out and say.

Comment: Thanks for replay it's working fine but i have two more classes  like Login.class and Jobsearc.class i am calling jobsearch.class from login.class and want to opne Jobsearch.class with tab bar

Comment: Just clear in one thing. Eachtab have seperate activity. If you click that tab it show that. So you need to dispaly tabs to your class login.class and jobsearch.class then you need to create two more tabs , or you need to create another tabwidget in that xml files.

Comment: no i don't want to show this activity in tab bar i only want to show tab with previous menu  when open job search class

Answer (score 0):

When you are moving to a new activity you are building a whole new view which means that the view you where just on gets thrown out and replaced with this new one. If you want the tab bar you need to build it into this new activity like you did for the first activity.