# Change custom tab Indicator on selected event for Android TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

If I use a custom view to set the tab icon/indicator, how could I specify the view or the specify the one when the tab is selected?  (There's a reason I cannot use string with a drawable resource that contains selector/items with different images for different states)

```
View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext());
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpecProjectUpdates = mTabHost
   .newTabSpec("ProjectUpdates")
   .setIndicator(tabview)
```

Do I need to make changes onTabChange event specifically?  Can I keep it custom without polluting the code with more event listeners?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373443/how-to-set-tab-view-indicator-background-color-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312474/how-to-change-the-color-of-tab-indicator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897268/tab-bar-not-showing-when-call-new-activity/20898035?noredirect=1#comment31367246_20898035

see this link which i posted earlier.

Comment: That approach works but not if I want to change state with a different image or change the content of the tabview. It only change background color/image on state change.  But if you want better control of it like if I switch to another set of imageview and textview inside of it, that can't be done.  I begin this approach because another library android-viewbadger.  When I tag a badge on the tab, the badge doesn't show up on a fully filled bitmap or select/item with image.  It works when I specify imageview with id.

Comment: Shayan pouratan, thanks for the reference link.  I gave it another try using selector in LinearLayout as suggested in the  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312474/how-to-change-the-color-of-tab-indicator Thanks a lot.